# Overriding file input button with custom button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to style input type=file.

When I try to override the deault button with my custom buttom (so that I can styel it). The problem I am facing is when ever I click my custom button the form gets submitted and validation kicks in. Is there a way I can fix it.

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" class="upload"/>
<button class="fileButton" id="fileButton">Choose File</button>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Contact Me" class="supportButton"></input>
```

Last input is my form submission button.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#fileButton').click(function(){
 $('#upload').click();
 alert("input");
 });
</script>
```

When I click my custom button, it triggers the file uplaod button ( I can browse and upload file) but at the same time it submits the form.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw5wqxpw/

Comment: i think its working fine you only have to include jquery in fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `type="button"` it won't submit a form. Default `type` for `button` if not declared is `submit`. Thus when you are clicking on it it submits the form as default behavior would expect

```
<button type="button" class="fileButton" id="fileButton">Choose File</button>
```

Comment: don't feel bad, have done this by accident myself numerous times

Answer (score 2):

You need to suppress the default action of clicking on a button:

```
$('#fileButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#upload').click();
    alert("input");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add **jquery** file to you code.then use `trigger` function in jquery 
it will work

```js
 $('#fileButton').click(function(){
 $('#upload').trigger("click");
 });
```

```css
.upload{
    display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" class="upload"/>
<button class="fileButton" id="fileButton">Choose File</button>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Contact Me" class="supportButton"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

When your function runs the `$('#upload').click()` line, it is actually simulating the button being clicked as it is shorthand for `.trigger("click")`, and then the submit button's default behavior is triggered. 
I think the function you need is `$('#upload').on("click", clickHandler)`.

Answer (score 1):

By default `type` attribute is `submit` which makes your form to submit, use `type='button'` instead:

```
<button class="fileButton" id="fileButton" type='button'>Choose File</button>
```